# How to handle windows authentication popup in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, protractor

I am new to protractor and facing an issue while handling the authentication pop up in protractor. Please find the attached screenshot.

[image: Authentication PopUp]

Please suggest me any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer for your question.

As this window is due to the Windows Authentication the easiest method to pass it is to run your tests using the correct Windows AD user.

1. If you run this test locally you can run the terminal using the `Run as different user` functionality in Windows context menu.
2. If you run it on CI server you can setup your agent to be executed on specific test user from AD
3. You can also try to use Firefox Profile to automate this setup: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

Answer (score -1):

You may try disable the proxy in the settings -> Options -> search "Proxy" -> No Proxy

[image: Please find the screenshot below]